# In rebase conflicts, how to say "use file from branch A, blow away file from master"?

Tags: git, github

I am pulling a branch from github, `my-new-branch`, in order to review it. It has minified build files in (I know, I know). I am unsurprisingly getting a conflict in the minified file when I pull/rebase.

I don't want to manually review every change in the minified file. I just want to say "use the file from `my-new-branch`, blow away the file from master, continue rebasing".

How can I do this?

Comment: `git rebase -m --strategy=recursive -X ours/theirs`. Refer to `git merge --help` and `git rebase --help` for details.

Comment: @ElpieKay: Beware, `-X theirs` does not mean use their *file*, it means use their *change* in case of conflicts.  I'll add an example in an answer.

Comment: @torek I think @Richard means `use the change`. If what he wants is really the file, `git pull` or `git rebase` is not a proper action.

Comment: Thanks both. I just want to end up with the file from `my-new-branch` - I know that there aren't any changes to the unminified source files, so the "conflicts" in the minified file are meaningless noise. (Merge conflicts in other files, however, might be real.) What's the best way to ensure that I end up with the file from `my-new-branch` without having to merge manually?

Answer (score 4):

First let me put in the usual notes:

- `git pull` is essentially `git fetch` followed by `git merge` or `git rebase`.  It does the rebase instead of the merge when you tell it so, via `--rebase` or a configuration entry.  In general, I prefer to use the two separate commands, although for specific cases where I'm sure in advance that I want either a regular merge or a rebase, I will use `git pull`.

  This matters a lot because in merge vs rebase the ours/theirs roles get swapped, because...
- `git rebase` is essentially a sequence of repeated `git cherry-pick` operations, done on a new, temporary, anonymous branch.  Once all of your to-be-rebased commits have been successfully cherry-picked into the new anonymous branch, Git peels your branch label off the old chain of commits, pasting it onto the new chain.

  This means that when you are rebasing, your *current* branch is an anonymous branch, and the branch from which each commit comes—which Git calls "theirs", as in `--theirs` or `-X theirs`—is actually your own branch.  The branch that Git calls "ours", as in `--ours` or `-X ours`, *will be* your branch, but it isn't yet!  For the very first step in particular, the anonymous branch points to the commit you are rebasing onto, which is the new commit(s) you brought in when you (or your `git pull`) ran `git fetch`.  In other words, it's *their* commit, not yours, even though Git refers to it with `--ours`.
- By contrast, when you are merging (`git merge`), Git stays on your own branch, and `--ours` and `-X ours` refers to your branch while `--theirs` and `-X theirs` refers to their branch.

Most people find this ours/theirs role-swap at least a bit confusing, so if you're confused, you are not alone.  I think it helps if you practice with `git cherry-pick`, but even then it can still be tricky.

Now, on to the practical steps of actually doing the rebase.

Let's say you start out on branch `bra`:

```
$ git checkout bra
```

Next, you do something like:

```
$ git rebase origin/master
```

to copy any commits you have on your `bra`, that are not also already on `origin/master`, so that they appear after the tip of `origin/master` on a new branch that will, in the end, be labeled `bra`.

Initially, you have this:

```
          E--F--G         <-- bra
         /
...--A--B--C--D           <-- origin/master
```

In the end, you will have this:

```
          E--F--G         [abandoned - original bra]
         /
...--A--B--C--D           <-- origin/master
               \
                E'-F'-G'  <-- bra
```

The first step in the rebase is figuring out which commits to cherry-pick.  Typically that's just "all commits on the original branch that are not on the target", i.e., `E`, `F`, and `G` in this case.

Next, Git checks out the tip commit of the target branch—commit `D`, here—as a "detached HEAD" (anonymous branch), and runs a loop of `git cherry-pick` commands (or something equivalent: exactly which command is used depends on which flags you give to `git rebase`).  The first one cherry-picks commit `E` to make copy `E'`.  Note that the *current* commit is now commit `D`.

This is where the ours and theirs flags come in.  Let's take a look at what [`git cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) does in more detail, since this is where you want to resolve your conflicts.

A cherry-pick starts by comparing a commit to its parent.  In this case, we're cherry-picking `E`, so we compare `E` against `E`'s parent commit, which is commit `B`.  This gets us a list of line-by-line changes: remove these lines, add some other lines as replacements.  Git now attempts to apply this diff (as a merge) against the current commit, which is `D`.  Note that there are also changes from `B` to `D`, so Git really can do a merge, with the usual merge conflicts and conflict resolution.

Let's say that one of the changes from `B` to `E` looks like this, in the `README` file:

```
@@ ... @@
 this is some context
-we ditched this
+and added this better line
 and kept this the same
```

If no similar change appears in `B`-to-`D`, Git takes one copy of this change.  But if, in `B`-to-`D`, we have this instead:

```
@@ ... @@
 this is some context
-we ditched this
+to put in a superior line
 and kept this the same
```

Git declares a conflict: it is not sure whether the "superior" line is better than the "better" line, or vice versa.

Using `-X ours` or `-X theirs` tells git which line to prefer in the case of conflict.  Let's say you use `-X theirs`: this means *prefer the `B`-to-`E` change*.  This is because "our" change is the one from `B` to `D`: that's the (anonymous) branch we're on; "their" change is the one from `B` to `E`.

**This does not mean *"take their entire file"*.  It only means "take their *change*".**  Let's say that somewhere else in `B`-to-`D`, we also changed some spelling, but we never touched those lines in `B`-to-`E`.  Using `-X theirs` takes the `B`-to-`E` changes but *leaves the `B`-to-`D` changes alone*.

We can, instead, let Git stop the rebase at this point, and manually run:

```
$ git checkout --theirs -- README
```

or:

```
$ git checkout <id of commit E> -- README
```

This means "take the entire file from commit `E` exactly as it appears in commit `E`", i.e., discard any `B`-to-`D` changes.

Once we've resolved the conflicts—by automatically taking "their" (`E`'s, which is ours) changes with `-X theirs`, or by manually taking "their" (`E`'s) file(s) with `git checkout --theirs`, and manually continuing the cherry-picking rebase process:

```
$ git rebase --continue
```

—Git makes new commit `E'` using the resolved `README`, and goes on to cherry-pick commit `F`, by doing an `E`-to-`F` diff and applying that to commit `E'`.

Depending on what we put into commit `E'`, this may apply cleanly, or may get more merge conflicts.  If this gets more merge conflicts, Git handles them according to our instructions, the same way as before.

Last, Git cherry-picks commit `G` by doing a diff from `F` to `G` and applying that to `F'`.

To finish the rebase, Git simply peels the branch label `bra` off `G` and makes it point to `G'` instead.  Commits `E--F--G` are now abandoned (though they are still in your reflogs, and will therefore remain in your repository for at least more 30 days by default).